# I need this loop to end after the index being asked for is no longer in the string, i keep getting this message and dont know how to fix it

Tags: indexing, syntax

I continue to get this error when I run the program. I need the program to end when the index asked for is not in the string.

```
code = input("Message? ")
index = 0
for c in code:
    print(code[index], end=" ")
    index = index + 3
```

And I am getting following error:

```
Message? cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
c h a l l e n g e Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
        print(code[index], end=" ")
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: When asking a question about code, it is always necessary to add a tag for the language you're using. Please [edit] to do so, and while you're at it format your code properly so that it's readable. Click the ? button at the top right while editing if you need help figuring out the formatting.

Answer (score -1):

You are advancing your index by 3, but your loop doesn't check if the index's new value is less than the length of the string.

It's hard to tell what you are looping on with your code formatted so badly, (and I'm not even sure what language it's supposed to be in.) But I'm guessing you are looping through every character in the variable code, but increasing your index by 3 not 1 so your loop doesn't match your increment.